# Why do we even need a cache?

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

So as I understand it, the cache is a copy of the RAM that is grouped together so that execution is faster given spatial and temporal locality.  But why not just immediately access the RAM and cut out the middle man?  Why do we need to access the cache, which copies the memory (sometimes not even the correct part)?

Comment: Cache is faster than RAM.

Comment: Okay, how is it faster? What are the specific reasons? I'm just learning about this all now, so I'm just trying to figure it out.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache

Comment: And your first attempt to research this question on your own did not reveal any difference between caches and dram? Something to do with latency perhaps?

Answer (score 4):

Here is the numbers for you, hope they will answer your question

```
          0.5 ns - Execute typical instruction
          1   ns - Fetch from L1 cache memory
          5   ns - CPU L1 CACHE branch misprediction
          7   ns - Fetch from L2 cache memory
        100   ns - Mutex lock/unlock
        100   ns - Fetch from main memory
     20,000   ns - Send 2K bytes over 1Gbps network
    250,000   ns - Read 1MB sequentially from memory
 10,000,000   ns - Fetch from new disk location (seek)
 10,000,000   ns - Read 1MB sequentially from disk
150,000,000   ns - Send packet US to Europe and back
```

[Source](http://norvig.com/21-days.html#answers)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want RAM if you have hard drive with TB? :)

Comment: how is that? they are completely separate things.